# Laravel Cookie::get returns null

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

Good day,

I have been struggling with this for the past few hours but admittedly I'm not very familiar with Laravel.

I use this row of code to generate a cookie:

```
return Response::make(view("/play"))->withCookie(cookie('username', $request->input('username'), 60000));
```

I have logged `$request->input('username')` and it is not empty, 
the application goes to the /play view but when I use `Cookie::get('username')`in a later method in another Controller later on it returns null.

[picture of cookie storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC1wu.png) it also does not appear empty in the browser.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Request()->cookie('username')